# Google maps api v3 shows a static image instead of an interactive map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sometimes, when I load the map I get an static image (and without markers) instead the interactive map with their markers and controls.

I think this is a feature for slow connections:

http://code.google.com/intl/es-AR/apis/maps/articles/static+js.html

But then, there's an error in the API, because I'm stuck in that static image, the map is never loaded.

Do you know if is possible to disable the static image in APIv3 and force the interactive map to be loaded every time?

Comment: Please show your code.  I have never seen this behavior happen automatically.  I have only seen it where the Static Maps API is explicitly implemented in the code.

Comment: You can see in the link that the v3 API implements natively this behavior. My code is very simple, the same of the basic tutorial, but I'm loading the map in a small div (400x250) and with slow connections, sometimes (not always) only the image of the map is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEWER/UPDATED ANSWER**: Apparently, you used to be able to suppress this behavior by setting `useStaticMap: false` in your MapOptions object.  However, there are reports that this stopped working around March. See [this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/659ddc17bb442c4b). Perhaps it was restored and perhaps it wasn't.  Searching for "useStaticMap" in the minified JavaScript code for Google Maps API v3 does yield a hit, so that's promising.

Note also the message in that thread that says that the name of the property was changed to useStaticMapImpl.  A cursory search in the JavaScript doesn't locate that string, but if useStaticMap doesn't work, then that may be worth a shot too.

Again, good luck!  If I could replicate this problem, I might be able to test some of these suggestions before shooting them off, but alas, I can't seem to make this happen, for whatever reason.

**OLD ANSWER**: I've been trying to get the behavior you describe to happen by slowing down my network connection using SpeedLimit on a Mac.  I have been unable to do so.  From that I conclude that perhaps if the problem is a slow connection, it might be a **very** slow connection.  Therefore I suspect that disabling the feature may result in a map that simply doesn't load at all.

I can't find anything in the API Reference that would indicate an option for this feature.  In fact, judging solely from the API Reference, this failover-to-static-maps thing doesn't exist.  Although I do see where it is alluded to in the link you provide, so maybe the API Reference is incomplete.

All that said, if you wanted to try to disable the behavior, you might be able to do it by listening for a `tilesloaded` and/or `idle` event on the Map object.  (The `idle` event supposedly fires when the map is loaded and ready to use, but the `tilesloaded` event seems like the more intuitive one.  You may need to experiment to see which, if either, give you the result you want.)  You could basically hide the `<div>` until the appropriate event fires.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that the event is never fired because the map is never loaded, just the static image. I'm testing with a connection of 128kbps (3G limited). Maybe the problem is the browser, because for example, now, when I entered to SO, the site didn't work well (I think some JS was not loaded). And something similar happens with Gmaps, sometimes the map is loaded fine after the static image, sometimes only the static image is loaded.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Apparently there used to be an undocumented way to suppress the static map.  Not sure if it still works, but worth a shot, I suppose.

Comment: Hi Trott, I can't replicate the problem now because now internet is working fast, but I'm pretty sure is not a problem of Gmaps, maybe the connection is lost in the middle of downloading the api or something like that. Anyway, if I see the problem again I'll try what you said, thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer to your question, but I was having the same problem and found out that I was loading the API twice by mistake. Once I removed the duplicate script it all started working again.

Comment: You made me check my app and this help me fix my issue! Thanks!

Comment: It's probably more common than we think!

Comment: OMG can't believe I was making such a school boy error. Thank you.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I had a map loading in an iFrame, and both that and the parent page were loading the API, resulting in a static image. Thanks